# Calculate coordinates inside radius at each time point

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've got a function that returns a count of which coordinates are located inside a provided radius. This works fine but I'm hoping to adjust this function so it can return a zero count if points are not located within the radius for a give time point.

At the moment, the function subsets the df by returning points that are located with in circle radius. It then performs a `groupby` to count these points.

I'm not just not sure which method would be more efficient. Leave the function as is and just resample the time series and fill new rows with `0`. Or update the function and remove the subset.

The circle is generated from `mainX`, `mainY`. The points for each unique time stamp are located in `X, Y`. The first time stamp contains two points, the second contains none and the third contain 2.

I want to count the number of points located with the radius. But I want to include time points that have none. So insert a zero here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : ['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3'],
    'Group' : ['X','Y','X','Y','X','Y','X','Y','X','Y','X','Y'],                    
    'Label' : ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],                 
    'X' : [1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,4,6,8,10],
    'Y' : [11,12,13,14,11,12,13,14,13,14,6,4],
    'mainX' : [3,3,3,3,10,10,10,10,5,5,5,5],
    'mainY' : [12,12,12,12,14,14,14,14,13,13,13,13]
    })

def in_circle(df, center_x, center_y, x, y, radius = 2):

    square_dist = (center_x - x) ** 2 + (center_y - y) ** 2

    df = df[square_dist <= radius ** 2]

    df = df.groupby(['Time','Group'])['Label'].size().reset_index()

    df = df.pivot(index = 'Time', columns = 'Group', values = 'Label').reset_index()

    df.columns.name = None

    return df

df = in_circle(df, df['mainX'], df['mainY'], df['X'], df['Y'])

print(df)

  Time  X  Y
0    1  1  1
1    3  1  1
```

Intended output:

```
  Time  X  Y
0    1  1  1
1    2  0  0
2    3  1  1
```

Comment: Wanted to mention that if you plan to do multiple lookups of this sort and/or have many points, there are ways to preprocess your points so that "which of these points are within radius of (x,y)?" returns much much much faster.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: is what you need `df[points]`?

Comment: @jonboy thanks for the clarification.  In that case, is what you're looking for this: `points = in_circle(df['mainX'], df['mainY'], df['X'], df['Y']); print(df[points])`? That results in the intended output you displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep changing to your function minimal, you may modify your function as follows:

**Method** 1: use `groupby` and `unstack`

- convert the boolean result of `square_dist <= radius ** 2` to integer and groupby it directly on `df.Time, df.Group`
- sum each group of groupby and rename axis names to appropriate names
  and `unstack` the series to dataframe.
- `reset_index` to put `Time` back to the dataframe

Codes:

```
def in_circle(df, center_x, center_y, x, y, radius = 2):

    square_dist = (center_x - x) ** 2 + (center_y - y) ** 2

    return ((square_dist <= radius ** 2).astype(int).groupby([df.Time, df.Group]).sum()
                                        .rename_axis(['Time', None]).unstack()
                                        .reset_index())

df_final = in_circle(df, df['mainX'], df['mainY'], df['X'], df['Y'])

Out[117]:
  Time  X  Y
0    1  1  1
1    2  0  0
2    3  1  1
```

---

**Method 2**: use `pd.crosstab`

```
def in_circle(df, center_x, center_y, x, y, radius = 2):

    square_dist = (center_x - x) ** 2 + (center_y - y) ** 2

    return pd.crosstab(df.Time, df.Group, (square_dist <= radius ** 2).astype(int), 
                       aggfunc='sum').reset_index()

df_final = in_circle(df, df['mainX'], df['mainY'], df['X'], df['Y'])

Out[143]:
Group Time  X  Y
0        1  1  1
1        2  0  0
2        3  1  1
```